# Adding data to a DataFrame after running an if statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I created two dataframes of log-normal values and a third (empty) dataframe to fill with the results of an if statement. My will is:

1. verify if each value of df1 is greater or equal to the value of df2 having the same index.
2. when it is True I want to add the result to df3.
3. when it is False no value should be added.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
mu, sigma = 4., 1.3
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, 1000))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, 1000))
df3=pd.DataFrame()

n=0
for i in range(1000):
    rest=df1.loc[n]-df2.loc[n]
    if rest >= 0:
        df3.add(rest)
  
    n+=1
```

There is the following error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to compute the sum of the data or are you trying to append/concatenate the data frames?

Comment: Yes, i Would like to compute the difference (when the result is positive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use loop, use vectorized operation:

```
# As you did not specify column name x[0] is the column labelled 0
# and not the first column (even here if it's the same)
df3 = df1.sub(df2).loc[lambda x: x[0] > 0].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df3)

# Output
               0
0     120.431123
1    1048.761973
2      74.196523
3      43.360916
4      13.739260
..           ...
505    55.869539
506   435.917391
507    59.078519
508    71.689533
509    74.257906

[510 rows x 1 columns]
```

For Python, the condition `if rest >= 0:` doesn't mean anything. Python doesn't know how to deal with something like [-3, 1, 2, 0] >= 0.